# Capture Ajax Hits( Network Logs ) in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am automating a test case using **Selenium** for Autosuggestor which hits an ajax call having the word and version number of autosuggestor in Parameters. I want to capture the url being hit (containing these params) i.e. **network logs**. On browsing through internet I came across https://eveningsamurai.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/capturing-network-traffic-using-selenium-webdriverfirebug/   blog. But using this approach my firefox webdriver is  throwing the error - couldn't bind the port in 7500ms. Any suggestion is most welcome

Comment: Are u trying to capture the auto complete window for an Edit Box in the browser.

Comment: @Arun actually I am trying to get the network logs (hits for the autosuggestor)